How to recognize an audio when i provide a list of more than 4 language in azure using recognize_once()?
Azure Speech SDK has a limitation where it only supports detecting up to 4 languages simultaneously in the "DetectAudioAtStart" mode. To work around this limitation, I create batches of 4 languages from the languages_to_detect list and attempt to detect the language for each batch.But it is not able to recogize and giving me wrong answer. I am passing a bangali audio file and it is saying hindi. which is wrong. Below is the code for your reference:
import azure.cognitiveservices.speech as speechsdk

subscription_key = "00000000000000000000000000"
service_region = "westus"
audio_file_path = "C:\\yogesh_folder\\speech_bangla.wav"

# List of all languages to detect
languages_to_detect = ["en-US", "ml-IN", "ta-IN", "te-IN", "gu-IN", "kn-IN", "mr-IN", "pa-IN", "bn-IN", "hi-IN"]

# Configure speech recognition
speech_config = speechsdk.SpeechConfig(subscription=subscription_key, region=service_region)

# Audio configuration
audio_config = speechsdk.audio.AudioConfig(filename=audio_file_path)

# Initialize detected language
detected_language = None

# Iterate through batches of 4 languages
for i in range(0, len(languages_to_detect), 4):
    # Slice the batch of languages
    batch_languages = languages_to_detect[i:i+4]

    # Configure auto-detection of source language for current batch
    auto_detect_source_language_config = speechsdk.languageconfig.AutoDetectSourceLanguageConfig(
        languages=batch_languages
    )

    # Create a speech recognizer instance for current batch
    speech_recognizer = speechsdk.SpeechRecognizer(
        speech_config=speech_config,
        auto_detect_source_language_config=auto_detect_source_language_config,
        audio_config=audio_config
    )

    # Perform recognition
    print(f"Detecting speech in languages: {batch_languages}")
    result = speech_recognizer.recognize_once()

    # Check result
    if result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech:
        detected_language = result.properties.get(speechsdk.PropertyId.SpeechServiceConnection_AutoDetectSourceLanguageResult)
        print(f"Detected language: {detected_language}")
        break  # Exit loop if language is detected

# If no language is detected, provide feedback
if detected_language is None:
    print("No language detected.")



I am passing a bangali audio file and it is saying hindi. which is wrong. Below is the code for your reference:


Log the intermediate results to see what is being detected for each batch. The Audio file should be clear with good quality and check that it had not hit any rate limits or other restrictions from the API.

App.py:
        # Log recognized text
        recognized_text = result.text
        print(f"Recognized text: {recognized_text}")

        break  # Exit loop if language is detected

    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.NoMatch:
        print("No speech could be recognized")
    elif result.reason == speechsdk.ResultReason.Canceled:
        cancellation_details = result.cancellation_details
        print(f"Speech Recognition canceled: {cancellation_details.reason}")
        if cancellation_details.reason == speechsdk.CancellationReason.Error:
            print(f"Error details: {cancellation_details.error_details}")

# If no language is detected, provide feedback
if detected_language is None:
    print("No language detected.")

Result:

